# Speedlite Yongnuo YN685 / AF assist beam / IR light doesnt work anymore on Nikon D7100

Tags: nikon, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, infrared

yesterday I was shooting as a eventphotographer and suddenly my IR beam of the flash didn't work anymore. (Probably I changed some settings while talking with someone? Idk...)

Some quick facts:

- The flash is newer than 6 months old
- Unfortunately I don't have the YN wireless device to update to the latest version
- The IR flash works on an other (borrowed) Nikon Speedlight SB-600, so probably the camera settings are okay
- In the extra menu settings under "C.n04" -> AF is on 0:ON..

My camera is the Nikon D7100. 
does anyone have some ideas to help me?

Thank you very much,
bernd

Answer (score 2):

It's a Yongnuo, a/k/a a "disposable flash." Some last longer than others, but you should always have one more than you need with you when using them for a shoot. Eventually, you'll need the extra one.

Comment: I got one of the older versions as well and I never had thoses troubles. I am sending this one back and ordered a new one, maybe it's just a lemon.

Answer (score 0):

Check your camera settings anyway, they have to be just right for AF Assist light to work.  See D7100 manual page 233 about option A4, which has to be ON.  And then it must be AF-S mode (or Single Servo if AF-A).  And also, Center focus point selected in Single Point mode, or Auto Area mode.  See page 233 to ensure they are still right.